# How to restrict content of an xsd:complexType with attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm having trouble trying to add a `minLength` and `maxLength` restriction to this complex type.  Here's my original code:

```
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Division">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ID">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute ref="wd:type" use="optional" />
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute ref="wd:Descriptor" use="optional" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

I want to add this restriction but I don't know how to do that.

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:minLength value="0"/>
  <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

I know how to do this for a simpletype, but in a complextype I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think it should be the Division element.

Comment: Uh, the `Division` element already has an `ID` element in its content model.  It would help if you would [edit] your question and show sample valid XML.

Comment: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) answers to this and your previous questions when they've helped you. If [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39045446/290085) does not help you, please follow-up in comments to explain.  If [none of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2148983/user2148983?tab=questions)  are truly receiving acceptable answers, please read [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define and name a `xs:simpleType` and extend that in your `xs:complexType`.

Here is a complete, working example (with dangling `xs:attribute/@ref` occurrences replaced with temporary `xs:attribute/@names` so the example can stand on its own):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Division">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ID">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="IDType">
                <xs:attribute name="attr1" use="optional" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="attr2" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="IDType">  
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="0"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```